# Is it possible to progressively alpha-blend between two textures in one location created with D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx?

Tags: c++, directx

I have two textures that are both .jpg, which represent a sky (one during the day, one at night).  My question is, is it possible for me to fade one texture into the other?  They are created with `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemoryEx`.  How can I perform this kind of transition?  I don't wish to create two objects, just change the texture gradually.

To be clear, I wish to, over time, slowly blend from one texture to another (and back).  However, I don't wish the fade to be going on at all times.  Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few options here -

You can use both textures with texture blending to transition from one texture to the other.

However, if you're doing this over a long period of time, you may want to precompute a third texture (the blended state) and just use it as a single texture.  Occasionally, recompute the "new" state.  This will potentially simplify your rendering, since you'd be using a single texture (that you change slowly over time) instead of having to always do multi-texturing just for this effect.  (If you're not doing anything else but this with the objects you're texturing, and if the textures aren't huge, a simple 2 texture multi-texture is no big deal, though.)

Comment: how is texture blending done?  do the files need to be .pngs for this to work, or do .jpgs suffice?

Comment: The texture blending happens on the GPU - either through multitexturing or as part of your shader.  The format is irrelevant at this point, since they're all just D3D textures.

Comment: Interesting.  How can one perform this over a span of time to move slowly between two separate textures?

Comment: You just increase the interpolation coefficient slowly over time. Do a search for *linear interpolation* and *rendering to texture buffers/render targets*.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pixel shader.

```
float t : register(c0);

float4 t1 = tex2D(g_sampler1, texcoord);
float4 t2 = tex2D(g_sampler2, texcoord);

float4 result = lerp(t1, t2, t);
```

where you pass in t as your linear interpolation amount.  t = 0.0 gives you the first texture, t = 1.0 gives you the second texture, and it interpolates linearly in-between.

Your file format then makes no difference, and it avoids a third texture being computed.